# Realm java advanced query instead of for-each for search inside list ids

Tags: java, realm

i have a model like this

```
    public class WorkDB extends RealmObject {
        private String address;
        private RealmList<ReportDB> reports;

        getters setters
    }

public class ReportDB extends RealmObject implements Serializable{
    private int idReport;
    private String nameReport;
    private RealmList<ReplieGroupDB> repliesGroup;
    private RealmList<QuestionGroupDB> questionGroups;

    getters setters
}

public class QuestionGroupDB extends RealmObject {

    private int idQuestionGroupInReplie;
    private String nameQuestionGroupInReplie;
    private RealmList<QuestionDB> questions;
    private int times;
}
```

How can i do a query like

```
realm.search(WorkDb.class).where(id,20).and(ReportDb.class).where(idReport,1).and(QuestionGroupDB.class).where(idQuestionGroupInReplie,2);
```

To avoid do a query to get WorkDB and do a for each in reports to find by id, and then, other do a other for each in questionGroupsDB to find any by id..

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you expect the output of your query to be. Do you want WorkDB, ReportDB, QuestionGroupDB  or QuestionDB's?

Comment: Hi, sorry, bad explication. I have a list of work, each dbwork has a list of reportdb, each reportdb has a list of qiestiongroupdb, then that I want is search a work by Id, inside it a reportdb by id and inside it a a questiongroupdb by I'd to avoid iterate list and compares ids. Thanka

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear to me what you expect the output to be? You want the query result to be a list of QuestionDB?

Comment: Yes. I want to do queries to search inside realmlist contained in realmobject

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve a list QuestionDB objects there is unfortunately no other way around it than building a manual query like the one you describe. We have a concept called BackLinks on our TODO (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607) which would make it possible to do the sort of query you are looking for, but currently you will have to do it manually. Sorry.